# Jailbroken iPad stuck on black screen

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios

I was looking around on Cydia until it suddenly froze then after a few minutes the screen turned black. I know that it is on because when I press the lock button and home button at the same time, I can hear the camera sound from the screenshot but it's still a black screen. I tried everything I could think of but nothing works.

Comment: "I tried everything I could think of but nothing works." And what would they be?

Comment: Well, I charged it and then changed the charger into an unused one and connected it to my laptop (it can still read all the data in the folders)

Answer (score 2):

Hold Power button and Home button down, then once you see the Apple logo keep hold of Volume Up until it boots. You can then uninstall your last tweak and restart.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *same buttons as when taking a screen shot*, **Home + Power**.

Hold **both Home and Power down for 15-20 sec** or until the Apple logo appears. This will hard-restart the iPad. You will not lose any information.

Answer (score -1):

hey there look maybe you are downloading  winterboard but i recomend you not to use it cuz it made my i pad crash 7 or 6 time a day (this is not true) so press the fome and the power sleep wake botton for **15 or 20 sec then it will work
bye**